# What are the RTP Libraries in Python with good RTCP Support?

Tags: python, open-source, rtp

I am looking for a RTP/RTCP Library that is open source.
I plan to use Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/). Open source multimedia framework

This is a good framework for doing RTP in. It is widely used on a number of platforms and has bindings in many different languages.

Here is a link to the [python bindings of GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-python.html)

Advantages to using GStreamer:

- Cross Platform
- Cross Language
- Comprehensive and simple API
- Good documentation
- Supports almost all multimedia
  formats.

Disadvantages:

- Adds a dependency
- Adds learning requirements to the
  project

Comment: Thank You, looks like I will be working from scratch. My requirements were not so large as what GStreamer brings in!

Comment: Does it have RTCP support?